# Gatsbyjs - Define Location of Static Pages as Something Other than the 'pages' folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

As the title states, I'm unsure if it is possible to customize the folder Gatsby looks into to generate static pages. Apparently, this seems to be fixed without the ability to change from the `pages/` folder. Ideally, this could be changed with something like an environment variable or similar. On the existing docs (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/) nothing like this is mentioned.

Does anybody know if this is possible and I've just missed it somewhere? I've also opened this feature request discussion on the Gatsby GitHub: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/35727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`gatsby-plugin-page-creator`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-page-creator/) (official plugin from Gatsby staff) to customize the source of the `/pages` folder. Simply use it as:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/account/pages`,
  },
}
```

Or using environment files:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/${process.env.A_FOLDER_NAME}`,
  },
}
```

You can even use multiple instances of the plugin or ignore some files with the `ignore` option.

I've tested it recently and worked like a charm.

---

The final configuration for this answer was:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`, 
    ignore: [`*`]     
  },
}
```

Comment: Hmmm theoretically this should be working but I'm getting 404 errors `GET http://localhost:8000/commons.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
cxWeb3.js:18 MEWCX Web3 provider injected
localhost/:452          GET http://localhost:8000/commons.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:452          GET http://localhost:8000/framework.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` - though I have quite some pages, due to many locales, about 1200 right now... is there an issue with how long it takes to load in development mode? I just checked my original simple build, that's still working...

Comment: It should work, either way, that's odd. Check the plugin's order because if you are using `i18` maybe the pages are generated before you've moved the  source `/pages` folder

Comment: Ah I finally got it! I didn't realize that `gatsby-plugin-page-creator` adds _additional_ page folders. If you want to override the default homepage (like I did), you have to add the following entry:

```javascript
{
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`,
    options: {
      path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
      ignore: [`*`]
    },
  }
```

It now works as expected. So to be super clear for anyone who finds it: You will have two entries of `gatsby-plugin-page-creator` if you want to completely override the default: one for your custom setup, one for the override.

Comment: Not to mention I had other general errors with my environment setup. This is still the correct answer :)